# How to create eps with transparent background?

Tags: transparency, postscript, eps

I like to create an .eps file with a transparent background. I tried Gimp and InkScape but it [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203213/imagemagick-convert-eps-to-png-setting-background-color) I haven't been successful.

Is the a special trick for this or is my software just not capable of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

EPS has an optional embedded preview image which may be a TIFF or BMP image with whatever transparency options those formats offer.

For the vector graphic portion (the PostScript) part, you will need to construct a clipping path around the desired portion of the image. The portion outside the path will not be marked when including the EPS in a composited PS file.

Comment: Where did you find this false information? Please see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28graphic%29#Transparency_in_PostScript http://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-eps-file-transparent-background-52652.html

Comment: In the postscript manuals, editions 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Those operators give you transparency of a sort in the composition of images, and in the preview, but you **cannot** remove the background entirely from the vector image. It will be white. Ie. you cannot "create an .eps file with a transparent background". Of course various programs may have special tricks for accomplishing this, it's not standard.

Comment: As far as I know the Wikipedia page is not wrong and for example the clipping path is usable. I agree that its use is not always easy or possible to completely define the transparency as needed.

Comment: Hmm. You're right. Using the clipping path should work. I'll edit.